# jQuery sortable update the whole set of data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a HTML list like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="31">
              list item
        </li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="32">  
               list item            
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="33">  
               list item            
        </li>
</ul>
```

and the following jQuery function:

```
$("#sortable" ).sortable({
   update: function(e,ui){
     $.ajax({
       url:'/ajaxUpdateOrder', 
       data: {
         id: ui.item.attr('id'),
         position: ui.item.index()
       }
     });
   } 
});
```

It works fine, but what I need instead is to pass the whole set of `IDs` and `priorities` in order to update every record and not just the one thas has been dragged.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

**Edit**

With a lot of helo from one of the members, I have managed to modify the function like following:

```
    $("#sortable" ).sortable({
       update: function(e,ui){
         var lis = $("#sortable li");
         var ids = lis.map(function(i,el){return {id:el.id, priority:el.dataset.priority}}).get();
         console.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url:'/BetterMeetings/meetings_tasks/ajax_update_order', 
           data: {
             ids:ids
           }
         });
       } 
    });
```

However, the data that I get in console is like this:

```
[{"id":"157"},{"id":"158"},{"id":"159"},{"id":"156"},{"id":"160"},{"id":"161"},{"id":"162"},{"id":"163"},{"id":"164"}]
```

so it is still missing the priority order.

Comment: that depends on what your backend expects, show an example

Comment: I only have backed solution written for single record update, so basically any type of data sent to the service would do, since I am going to adapt backend function for this. An array of arrays I believe would be a good way to go, it is just that I cannot figure the jQuery out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add data-fields to your html tags:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="31" data-priority="2">
          list item 31
    </li>

    <li class="ui-state-default" id="32" data-priority="4">  
           list item 32       
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="33" data-priority="8">  
           list item 33
    </li>
</ul>

$("#sortable" ).sortable({
   update: function(e,ui){
     var lis = $("#sortable li");
     var ids = lis.map(function(i,el){return {id:el.id, priority:el.dataset.priority}}).get();
     console.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
     $.ajax({
       url:'/ajaxUpdateOrder',
       method:'POST',
       data: {
         ids:ids
       }
     });
   } 
});
```

Live on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kdqm98u/4/

As you see the array you post `[{"id":"31","priority":"2"},{"id":"33","priority":"8"},{"id":"32","priority":"4"}]` contains all the id-s in priority order (after I moved 33 to be the 1st one), so in the backend you have all the priorities in order according to this array.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I just get the `Illegal invocation` error.

Comment: @WpDoe, updated answer and jsfiddle. I forgot to add .get(). If you still get error, please give me more specific detail: which line, what browser you use. Does the jsfiddle work for you? You have to open the javascriopt console, and it'll print the ids in an array there

Comment: Thank you once again for you asnwer. The jQuery function now works, however in only returns the IDs, when what I have stated previously, I need to provide to arguments with element: `id` and `order/priority` number.

Comment: @WpDoe ids has all the id-s in priority order, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Well not exactly. The id-s in the example represent id-s in database so that I could get exact db records, but every record has a column called `priority` and that is where the order is stored.

So basically I need to send something similar to `[[33, 1], [32, 2], [38, 3]]`

Comment: @WpDoe, I'm sorry, this is the 1st time you talk about this, it's not mentioned in the question, how could I guess it? Please update the question with example data with priority. Or do you want me to add it to my example?

Comment: I added the priorities to my answer

Comment: I have just fixed the code but, the array looks like this: [{"id":"157"},{"id":"158"},{"id":"159"},{"id":"156"},{"id":"160"},{"id":"161"},{"id":"162"},{"id":"163"},{"id":"164"}].

I will update the question with exact code snippet that I use.

Comment: @WpDoe, let me quote you: "I only have backed solution written for single record update, so basically any type of data sent to the service would do, since I am going to adapt backend function for this". You're welcome to open a new, specific question how to do that change.

Comment: what I need is exactly what you have posted: `[{"id":"31","priority":"2"},{"id":"33","priority":"8"},{"id":"32","priority":"4"}]` However the priority order just does not make it into the JSON data with the snippet that you wokred out.

Comment: @WpDoe, try adding `method:'POST',` If still not working, then please send me the POST data you received in the server

Comment: Dear Gavriel, I have updated the question with the snippet currently in use and the data that is received. I do the POST request, but it still does not include the priorities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102370/discussion-between-gavriel-and-wpdoe).